# Android duplication on Fragment Transaction

Tags: android, android-fragments

in my main activity i have this line to replace fragment with `viewgroup`

MainActivity:

```
public class ActivityMain extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.activity_main_container, new HomeFragment())
                .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

activity layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and my `HomeFragment` is:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    public HomeFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle saved) {
        super.onCreate(saved);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false);
        Log.e("HomeFragment", " onCreateView");
        return view;
    }
}
```

now after build application and run that on emulator, my code running duplicate `HomeFragment`, how can i prevent this action?

Comment: Where do you call `updateHomeFragments()` from, and what is the surrounding code?

Comment: @BenP. from onCreate in MainActivity

Comment: And do you call it every time `onCreate()` runs?

Comment: @BenP. i don't think. after run application in first time i see this action

Comment: @BenP. my post updated

Answer (score 1):

The framework will restore your fragment state when an activity is restored, such as after a configuration change.  You should only manipulate fragments the first time an activity is created.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if(savedInstanceState == null) {
        // set up your fragments
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Do like this if fragment is already launched don't perform transaction
>   again

```
private Class mFragmentClass; mFragmentClass = InfoFragment.class; 
if (null != mFragmentClass) { 
try { 
mFragment = (Fragment) mFragmentClass.newInstance();
if(mFragment instanceof (Fragment)mFragmentClass){
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager(); fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_navigation_menu, mFragment).commit(); 
} catch (InstantiationException exception) { exception.printStackTrace();
 } catch (IllegalAccessException exception) { exception.printStackTrace(); }
}else {
//do nothing
}
```